# Cannot document Python functions in VS 2017

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2017, documentation

I coded Python in VS years ago, and there was an automated way to document the functions (so intellisense shows it), but I cannot remember how it worked. Maybe it is not installed on VS 2017.

(Note: intellisense works, I need to automatically fill the documentation text)

I think that it was a snippet that automatically inserted a documentation template after I wrote """, but I checked all the python snipets, and there is none for documentation

I googled it, and only found snippets for VS Code, even when I explicitly search "visual studio 2017"

Should install an extension/plugin?

Comment: Intellisense should pick it up if you do proper python coments. I.e. `"""` inside of the functions/methods/classes.

Comment: That being said I recommend using VS code for python. Though VS 2017 is good for the C family (C, C++, C#) I have found it is much easier to work with python in VS Code.